# Unexpected LaTeX cmd Errors

Tags: fonts, luatex, koma-script, xparse

I have a tex-document with the `scartcl` class.
In the preamble I redefine `\it` by `\RenewDocumentCommand{\it}{...}{...}`.
Moreover, I have to different environment in which I want to comple the document with LuaLaTeX.

1. Version 1.13.0 (TeX Live 2021/CVE-2023-32700 patched) (on my local machine)
2. Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Debian) (within a podman container)

In the older version on my local machine everything works fine.
I searched the log for "err", "warn" and "depr" and did not find anything concerning.

However, in the newer version in the container I get `! LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\it' undefined`. As well as an error that says that the old font command `\it` will not work anymore.
I tried to fix the first problem by adding `\provideDocumentCommand{\it}`. That resulted in `LaTeX cmd Error: Invalid argument type '\RenewDocumentCommand ' in command` and the `scratcl` error remaining.

Can someone explain to me what the problem is here?

Ty,
Franz

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test.

Comment: it should be `\ProvideDocumentCommand\it{}{}`, or `\providecommand\it{}`

Comment: Ty, ... that was very stupid of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following short test file:

```
% franz.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\show\it
\end{document}
```

If I run on my system (where I keep TeX Live from 2012 on) with

```bash
/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex franz
```

I get

```
> \it=macro:
->\protect \it  .
l.2 \show\it
```

If I do instead

```bash
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex franz
```

I get

```
> \it=undefined.
l.2 \show\it
```

What happened? In the transition from TL 2021 to TL 2022, the koma classes changed the management of the old font commands. Until TL 2021, those commands were defined so that they would “work” also in the preamble. Later, they are “defined” only at begin document.

This is the cause of the difference: if you do `\RenewDocumentCommand{\it}{...}{...}` in the preamble, you get no error with TL 2021, because `\it` indeed has a definition. But you get the error with later releases because in the preamble `\it` is no longer defined.

Solution:

```
\providecommand{\it}{}% in case \it isn't defined
\RenewDocumentCommand{\it}{...}{...}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend reusing `\it` for any purpose.

Comment: If you really, really must use `\it` etc. with KOMA Script, there's a package to let you do that: https://github.com/komascript/defoldfonts You probably shouldn't, though: those commands have been obsolete since `LaTeX 2ε`, i.e. almost 30 years.